# Meaning of 世界圏内 in the following sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, words

Context: a speaker is talking about a boxer after a boxing match has just finished.

> ＯＰＢＦ５度目の防衛２ＲＫＯで決めたぁあ！！世界ももはや圏内だ！！！

What is the meaning of the second sentence? `"He can now aim at the world title"` or `"He is now a world-famous boxer"`? (OPBF is [Oriental and Pacific Boxing Federation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriental_and_Pacific_Boxing_Federation)) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the former, "He can now aim at the world title".

～[圏内](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%9C%8F%E5%86%85&ref=sa) is "within ～'s range". For example, 合格圏内 means having a good chance of passing an exam. You have correctly guessed that this 世界 refers to the world title.